# Triggers list not showing for C# in Visual Studio Code (Windows OS) for Azure Function App Project

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am learning to create an Azure Function App using VS code in c#. But When I select C# as the language I am not seeing any trigger list. But When I selected JavaScript I could see the trigger list. I don't know what I am missing. I am seeing below when try to select triggers:

[image]

But when I select JavaScript as the language I can see the list below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, any update?:)

Answer (score 0):

I can create the C# azure function by VS Code with no problem:

[image]

I can explain the principle to you, hoping to help you locate your problem. First of all, the UI interface you see is provided by the azure function extension plugin of VS Code. And this plugin will collect your input information then use commands offered by function-core-tools to create the function app.

So I guess the problem comes from the azure function extension plugin. You can try to uninstall the plugin and restart the VS Code, then re-install it. If still not work, you can follow this doc to create C# azure function directly with commands:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbrowser

These is the commands:

First, go to the folder in VS Code, open the terminal, then run:

`func init --dotnet`

`func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel "anonymous"`

The principle of this method is exactly the same as you use UI creation (UI plug-ins create azure functions by calling these console commands), so if there is really any problem that prevents the console from creating azure function, you will receive relevant informations in the terminal.

By the way, for C# azure function development, I recommend to use Visual Studio instead of VS Code(Because it is very comfortable to use that tool to develop C# Azure function.).

Comment: Thanks , this helped me to create the functions using the commands but the UI still not working

Comment: @BharathGajjala You don't need to care about these, they are essentially the same. It seems that there is a problem with the plugin. I encountered this situation once before, but it was inexplicably works some days later. I don't know why.

Comment: @BharathGajjala Hi, if my answer helps you create the functions successfully, can you mark my answer to end this question?:)